# Caching User Profile

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I have a struct that's something like the following:

```
Struct User {
    let name: String?
    let address: String?

    init(name: String, address:String) {
         self.name = name
         self.address = address
    }
 }
```

I'm trying to cache the users profile but I'm in doubt on the best approach to do it.

The struct example I gave above is a smaller size of my real struck which containes profile picture as well.

I already cache some useful stuff in [UserDefaults]  but I'm wondering if I should cache the user profile inside UserDefaults or CoreData?

If you think UserDefaults is the best approach, how can I store this Class-type into it? I can store simple booleans and so on, but how could I save a struct like the above, then fetch its data properly?

```
self.cacheUser = User(name: "Ivan", address: "EUA")
```

How could I cache the [cacheUser] into [NSUserDefaults] ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `NSKeyedArchiver` to archive the object and then an `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to unarchive the object, but it would have to conform to the `NSCopying` protocol.

You can also use `CoreData` to save the objects if they are more extensive and complex.

If there are not too many variables in the classes, you can simply put the variable names and values in a dictionary and save the dictionary to your user defaults. You can then fetch them and rebuild the object with the dictionary values saved in user defaults. But I would only do this if the objects are very simple (eg, a class with a couple Ints and/or Strings).

Ultimately, I suggest using `CoreData` for persisting custom objects. Because, as classes begin to get more and more complex, `CoreData` will give you much better performance and faster accessibility.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I will go with CoreData definitely. Thanks for the opinion